# How can I generate the metadata for my OData service

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using VS 2012. My server side is WebApi 4.5 and my client side application is WPF.

I want to consume my odata service at the client side using "Add Service Reference" but I don't know how to generate the metadata file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should point it to the root of your OData endpoint. If you're using the default routing, it's `http://<address>:<port>/odata`. If you've got a different routing, you should check your MapODataRoute line in WebApiConfig.cs.

**Clarification edit:**

The metadata itself can be found at `http://<address>:<port>/odata/$metadata`. However, as I said, in order to add it as a service reference, it should be sufficient to point just to the root.

Comment: http://<address>:<port>/odata is the address of my service. I'm asking about generating the metadata endpoint.

Comment: I am aware of that. I've updated my answer in order to clarify it more.